# SSH tuneling and machine selection

Tags: windows, terminal-server, ssh-tunnel

With putty on Windows I added some tunnel for terminal service through ssh

```
6664 > 192.168.20.44:3389
6665 > 192.168.20.45:3389
6666 > 192.168.20.46:3389
```

So when I connect with client to `127.0.0.1:6664` it works...

Now I want to use localtest.me to select the machine directly without port number.

I want when I type foo.localtest.me in TS client to connect automaticaly on the `127.0.0.1:3389` is it possible or do I need a proxy to translate port regarding domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be easier if you will just add and host entry for domain translation in windows hosts file
foo.localtest.me 192.168.20.46:3389 
Please have a look here http://www.technoreply.com/simple-trick-to-use-ports-in-hosts-file/ .

Comment: I try to avoid to type the port number each time to select the distance machine. with you solution that is not a solution you just tell me type the port

Comment: I might be mistaken , but with TS you can save the session (and keep the port number there). If TS is the terminal service client .

Comment: you right it keep session, I want to call a name, and not an ip adress, because I'have near 20 machine to access and I don't want to memorize the corespondance.

Comment: You can save the sessions under a meaningfull name , not by ip then you won't have to memorize them , or you could use a remote desktop organisor like mremote.